# Загрузка товаров на сайт WordPress c помощью db (php)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Всем привет! в этом деле нет большого опыта, но вот столкнулся с задачей когда на сайт на WP нужно загрузить каталог ( 100 + позиций) подскажите алгоритм действий, та и вообще как лучше это реализовать? Как я понимаю нужно создать отдельную страницу, написать функцию php, создать db и это все дело закинуть в тему WP?

Comment: Была задача вытащить из документа ворд 500 записей, сохранил документ в  html, потом распарсил все это дело и добавил на сайт через [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_insert_post) Аналогично можно сделать с других сайтов или же с каталогов пк

Comment: Я бы хотел уточнить, в каком виде на данный момент хранятся посты?

Comment: на данный момент четко сформированного нет, есть папка с фото продукции и ее названием

Comment: Названия в каком виде? Если папка называется как товар, уже хорошо. Уточните есть ли дополнительные галереи товара?

Comment: нет, есть вот папка с каталогом турбин и под каждой турбиной ее название, я  так понимаю мне эту папку нужно залить в БД и написать функцию на php потом ? и этот файл страницы закинуть в WP?

Comment: Было бы не плохо если бы показали вашу структуру папок и файлов товаров.

Comment: Вы можете  создать отдельную страницу, присвоить ей шаблон, а в шаблоне написать цикл. Для начала пройтись по всему каталогу. Найти папки с названием товара и фотографию в нем. Вытащить название папки записать в бд через  wp_insert_post 'post_title' => $product_name

Comment: Картинку добавляйте через wp_insert_attachment(), папки и файлы можете достать с помощью функции scandir()

Comment: Правильно я понял? я в новой странице подключаю шаблон свой wp, и в нем пишу функцию php?

Comment: @Юрец все верно. Что бы сделать шаблон, создайте в папки темы новый файл .php на первой строчки напишите <?php /* Template name: Парсер товара */  ?> Потом создайте в админ панели новую страницу и присвой те ей шаблон "Парсер товара"

Answer (score 1):

> на WP нужно загрузить каталог ( 100 + позиций) подскажите алгоритм
>   действий, та и вообще как лучше это реализовать?

Взять любой понравившийся плагин из оф. каталога для [импорта из csv](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/import+csv/)/xml/txt/etc.
И никогда не трогать базу.  Ну только когда есть твёрдое желание поломать сайт.